# Cannot connect to localhost

Tags: c, linux, unix, ip, localhost

I am running linux mint and have typed into the command terminal some commands to connect to my localhost but it keeps saying connection failed.

Here is what I type in:

```
echo "echo test" | ./<my executable> localhost <port #>
```

Here is my code for the connect:

```
  int r = connect(sock, addrList->ai_addr, addrList->ai_addrlen);
  if (r < 0) {
    printf("Connection failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }
```

Here is full code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Invalid arguments\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char *serverIP = argv[1]; /*Server hostname*/
  char *portNumber = argv[2]; /*Port Number*/
  void *numericAddress;
  char addrBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  in_port_t port;
  char buffer_stdin[65535];
  char buffer_stdout[65535];
  int bytes_read = 0;
  int bytes_written = 0;

  /*getting integral number of string representation of port number*/
  in_port_t servPort = atoi(argv[2]);

  /*------------------get binary number of hostname-----------------*/
  struct addrinfo addrCriteria;
  memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria));
  addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_INET;
  addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

  struct addrinfo *addrList;

  int rtnVal = getaddrinfo(serverIP, portNumber, &addrCriteria, &addrList);
  if (rtnVal != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo() failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  numericAddress = &((struct sockaddr_in *) (addrList->ai_addr))->sin_addr;
  /*Converting port to binary*/
  ((struct sockaddr_in *)(addrList->ai_addr))->sin_port = htons(servPort);
  /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  inet_ntop(addrList->ai_addr->sa_family, numericAddress, addrBuffer, sizeof(addrBuffer));
  printf("IP ADDRESS: %s\n", addrBuffer);

  /*Creating socket*/
  int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock < 0) {
    printf("error creating socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /*Establish connection to the echo server*/
  int r = connect(sock, addrList->ai_addr, addrList->ai_addrlen);
  if (r < 0) {
    perror("Connection failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /*Reading from stdin and writing to socket until stdin ends
  bytes_read = read(0, buffer_stdin, sizeof(buffer_stdin));
  write(sock, buffer_stdin, bytes_read);*/

  while ((bytes_read = read(0, buffer_stdin, sizeof(buffer_stdin)-1)) > 0) {
    write(sock, buffer_stdin, bytes_read);
  }

  /*Shutting down write end of socket*/
  int r_shutdown = shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
  if (r_shutdown < 0) {
    printf("Shutting down write end of socket failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /*Reading from socket and writing to stdout until socket ends*/
  while ((bytes_read = read(sock, buffer_stdout, sizeof(buffer_stdout)-1)) > 0) {
    write(1, buffer_stdout, bytes_read);
  }

  close(sock);
  exit(0);
}
```

Do I need to install something to connect to localhost?

Thanks

EDIT: OK here is an update:

First I type into the command terminal: chmod a+x exe (where exe is our UDP server)
then I type in: ./exe  e.g. ./exe 2525
then I type in: echo "echo test" | ./ localhost

But when this happens the terminal doesn't return "echo test" it just sits there just like if it was waiting for input from the user, or like if it was stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code.  Also, use `perror("Connection failed\n");` instead of `printf("Connection failed\n");` to see why the connect failed

Comment: alright i shall try that

Comment: it says ": connection refused". I shall post the rest of my code

Comment: OK, that means nobody is listening on that port (so there is nobody to accept your connection request)

Comment: our professor has provided us a server. we connect to the server, write to the socket, and read from the socket and write back to stout. we dont have access to the code thats in the server.

Comment: You posted an answer here what happened to it I think you were right

Comment: My previous answer was wrong (I missed that you were doing `htons(servPort)` later than I expected it, but it was there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to supply the localhost on the command line:

```
./exe localhost 2525
```

or:

```
echo test | ./exe localhost 2525
```

Comment: Still not working. I think you were right when you were talking about big endian vs little endian, because in our class the professor said this will be a big problem on projects if u don't use the right method. So which one should i give a try? htonl() instead of htons()?

Comment: I believe what you have is OK.  Does doing the command `netstat -an -A inet | grep :2525` show your professors listener running?  If not, that's the answer

Comment: ya nothing happens when I type that in. I don't get anything back. Which means?

Comment: talk to your professor (or his "Teaching Assistants", if any) -- his listener probably isn't listening/running or *perhaps* you are mistaken on the port#